# EWS java check if email is encrypted

Tags: java, encryption, office365, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to check if the email or part of email is encrypted so that I can return the email. According to this link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569286.aspx

The different types of email encryption options in Office 365 including Office Message Encryption (OME), S/MIME, Information Rights Management (IRM).

I sent one email from my outlook making it confidential, I can see the email body saying This message has been marked as Confidential. You've received an encrypted message from xxxxxx@xxx.com

To view your message

Save and open the attachment (message.html), and follow the instructions.

Sign in using the following email address: xxxxx@xxx.com 
Message encryption by Microsoft Office 365

When I loaded the content of the email message, in the content I found this

X-MS-Exchange-OMEMessageEncrypted: true

```
emailMessage.load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent));
```

is there a way to get to this property of the email message. because the property getItemClass is just returning this.[stack overflow question saying we can check this property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486144/ews-managed-api-is-there-a-way-to-identify-if-an-email-or-attachment-is-encryp)

```
emailMessage.getItemClass() -IPM.Note
```

Answer (score 0):

For RMS/IRM messages you can check the PidNameContentClass property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839681.aspx which on RMS messages gets set to rpmsg.message. You can access this as an Extended property eg

`ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.InternetHeaders,"content-class",MapiPropertyType.String);`